# Android Alert dialog button text are truncated

Tags: android, button, android-alertdialog

am showing long text in the alert button for the user action. But this been truncated.

How can we show multiple line text in button (alert).

```
final AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.create();

    alert.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface arg0) {
            alert.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.mdlivePrimaryBlueColor));
            alert.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.mdlivePrimaryBlueColor));
        }
    });
    alert.show();
```

Comment: Please show what you have done so far.

Comment: @il_raffa - Have updated the source

Answer (score -1):

[image]I just tried this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("HELLO");
builder.setMessage("TEST");   builder.setPositiveButton("LSDJFLJDSLFKDJSFLKDJSFLsdafsadfsadfsdafsadfsadfasdfasdasdfsadfasdfsdafsdafsdfadfsKD", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
        });
```

builder.show();

And the text wasn't cropped

Comment: have you tried for two buttons, am using appcompact v7 the dialog buttons displayed at right end.